# Python Circular Dependencies for Classes

Tags: python-3.x

Say we have two Python-3 classes called A and B. Class A has a function toB() that returns an instance of B, and class B has a function toA() that returns an instance of A.

We now create a unit test and import both A and B and test our functions A.toB() and B.toA(). We get an error reporting a circular dependency.

How does one solve this problem, if it is solvable and what is the correct solution for a large-scale project?

Comment: Seems like a design flaw to begin with. But you can always make one of the imports local inside the function body. That should resolve the circular import because it no longer happens at module loading time

Comment: Have a look at [typing.TYPE_CHECKING](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING)